# How to toggle class when clicked outside the element Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the first block of code opens and closes the .main-navigation while putting the shadow overlay over the page at the same time. But what I would like to accomplish is to click anywhere outside the navigation to do the same action(close the menu and remove the overlay) only if the menu is opened and overlay is over the page - so if those two classs are applied.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bfgb951w/

```
<header id="ovlay">
            <span class="nav-toggle eq">&equiv;</span>
            <nav class="main-navigation">
                <span class="nav-toggle">&times;</span>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#about" class="slide-section">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#works" class="slide-section">Works and stuff</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="slide-section">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header> 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('open');
        $('#ovlay').toggleClass('overlay');
    });
});

$(document).click(function(){
    if($('.nav-toggle').hasClass('open')) {
        $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('open');
        $('#ovlay').toggleClass('overlay');
    }
});
```

Comment: Provide a working example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: If I got your question right, you could use events like on blur or on focus out. Will that work?

Comment: added fiddle. @Vasis yes I stumbled across that one but couldn't get it work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the `open` class to the `.nav-toggle` element so while the `$(document).click()` fires, the if-statement within it always yields false. Change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('open');
        $('#ovlay').toggleClass('overlay');
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).click(function(event){
    if($('.main-navigation').hasClass('open') && $(event.target).closest(".main-navigation").length == 0) {
        $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('open');
        $('#ovlay').toggleClass('overlay');
    }
});
```

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1n78d9jq/

Note the added check in the document.click that prevents closing when the click is on the main menu itself.

Comment: hm seems to work for open-close, but still the menu closes if I click any of the links on it..

Comment: oh sorry, it seems to work in my browser, this happens only in fiddle. thank you! P.S. could you please explain why is the "return false" important, and why is the (".main-navigation").length == 0?

Comment: If you don't add the return false, the click on the menu also counts as a click on the document. The length check ensures that the close when clicking somewhere on the menu itself it doesn't close.